# Why does the GUI not run after the installation of FullProf Suite?

Tags: software-assistance, graphical-user-interface, fullprof-suite

I installed `Fullprof_Suite_March2021_Linux64.tgz` in Ubuntu 18.04. I also installed "libmotif-common" libraries. But all the GUIs are not opening. Why is this?

Comment: Do you get a particular error message when trying to open them? This may help someone to diagnose the problem.

Comment: Doesn't show any error message. But not open.

Comment: How are you trying to open the GUI? Is there a shell script that launches it, or is there an executable binary?

Comment: @Nithyadevi +1 but have you been able to consider the comment by S R Maiti? Without any interaction with the users that have tried to help, the question can get closed as "abandoned" so that the unanswered queue features more of the questions that are not abandoned. If you've found a solution to your problem, then if you can write an answer it would be very helpful for future users!

Comment: I can reopened this if the OP includes a bit more detail in the question (for example, addressing S R Maiti's comment).